# How to proxy with Gatsby and custom Webpack config (netlify-lambda)

Tags: webpack-dev-server, gatsby, netlify

I'm using **Gatsby** with **netlify-lambda** which creates a server for functions on the 9000 ports:

`http://localhost:9000/myFunctionName`

In production the address of the functions is:

`/.netlify/functions/myFunctionName`

So I would like to have a dev mode proxy that serves `http://localhost:9000/` when I call `/.netlify/functions`.

My custom Webpack config in `gatsby-node.js`:

```
exports.modifyWebpackConfig = ({ config, stage }) => {

  if (stage === 'develop') {

    config.merge({

      devServer: {
        proxy: {
          '/.netlify/functions': {
            target: 'http://localhost:9000',
            pathRewrite: {
              '^/\\.netlify/functions': ''
            }
          }
        }
      }

    })

  }

}
```

Does not work.

I tried this too https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/api-proxy/#api-proxy but I need to rewrite the url and not just prefix.

What's the best way to use **netlify-lambda** with **Gatsby** ?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure why you're adding it to gatsby's routing instead of using the default that is added to package.json? (this seems to be where you got it from:  https://github.com/netlify/create-react-app-lambda/blob/master/package.json#L19).  Perhaps you could expand on your use case?

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and it works well with create-react-app but not with Gatsby.
But I'm not a proxy pro, there may be something else to do ? I doesn't find doc on the proxy in package.json.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**: Gatsby now does support Express middleware, in [this merged PR](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/pull/4920). This will not support the Webpack Dev Server proxy configuration, but will allow using ordinary Express proxy middleware.

To use with `netlify-lambda` just add this to your `gatsby-config.js` :

```
const proxy = require("http-proxy-middleware")

module.exports = {
  developMiddleware: app => {
    app.use(
      "/.netlify/functions/",
      proxy({
        target: "http://localhost:9000",
        pathRewrite: {
          "/.netlify/functions/": "",
        }
      })
    )
  }
}
```

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/api-proxy/#advanced-proxying

---

Unfortunately, the Gatsby development proxy configuration is not at all extensible. Since Gatsby does not use the webpack dev server, its proxy options are not available. See https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/2869#issuecomment-378935446

I achieve this use case by putting an nginx proxy in front of both my Gatsby development server and the netlify-lambda server. This is a very simplified version of the proxy server config (trailing slash is important):

```
server {
    listen       8001;

    location /.netlify/functions {
        proxy_pass        http://0.0.0.0:9000/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass        http://0.0.0.0:8000;
    }
}
```

I'm using an nginx proxy anyhow, so that's not an undesirable amount of extra dev setup, but it would certainly be better if Gatsby supported this common case.

Comment: You may this link interesting: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/blog/2018-12-17-turning-the-static-dynamic/